# Directives and variables

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, using-directives

I have in my directive the controller and link in the following way:

```
myapp.directive('MyDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          ....
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
           $scope.variable = true;

        },
        templateUrl:  './app/templates/template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch('variable ', function(){
            console.log("variable : " + scope.variable )
          });
       }
       .....
```

I am not able to see the scope.variable in the block link. How I can resolve it?

Comment: Look again at how to use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: What do you mean by the "block link"?  Please include the relevant HTML as well.  If you are trying to watch a variable not in the directive's isolate scope, you are probably looking for something like `scope.$parent.$watch()`

Comment: I defined the $scope.variable into the directives' controller .I would like to  use it in the scope.watch.. I can try to use scope.$parent.$watch